# Do calculators have floating point error?

Tags: computer-science, arithmetic, calculator

As a programmer, we have been told about floating points errors on computer. Do Calculators have floating point error too?

Example.

```
0.1 (display) = .0999999998603016  (actual value used) on computers
```

Not really 0.1 But you can see it is close.

Comment: Every calculating machine that does inexact arithmetic  will have floating point error...

Comment: Calculators typically use decimal arithmetic and so can show "nicer" numbers than computers, which do binary arithmetic.

Comment: Also, calculators usually use more digits internally than they display.  This tends to reduce roundoff error, but it does not eliminate it.

Comment: "Calculators typically use decimal arithmetic" - more precisely, [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal).

Comment: I dont think calculators have round off errors as in floating points.

Comment: TomCat: “I dont think calculators have round off errors as in floating points.”  I think that you are right, but why did you ask the question if you know the answer?

Comment: I don't know the answer. I am fixing floating point error in my program. I want to use calculator to compare the result and show the error. Of course the more you discuss, the clearer it becomes, but no that is not the answer. I am not an authority on calculators and if I say it shouldn't have error, that does not mean it does not have floating point errors. May be a different algorithm is used. I know there is some error in calculators too.

Answer (score 3):

Calculators are computers, too; they're just smaller. Surely if we knew how to represent arbitrary real numbers inside calculators, we could do the same thing with desktop computers.

That said, it's possible—both on a calculator and on a computer—to represent *some* real numbers exactly. No computer I know of would represent $\frac12$ inexactly, since its binary expansion (0.1) is short enough to put inside a floating point register. More interestingly, you can also represent numbers like $\pi$ exactly, simply by storing them in [symbolic form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_computation). In a nutshell, instead of trying to represent $\pi$ as a decimal (or binary) expansion, you just write down the symbol "$\pi$" (or, rather, whatever symbol the computer program uses for $\pi$).

Comment: Calculators are, however, unlikely to represent $\pi$ symbolically.

Comment: If they did we would all be doomed. No body would use calculators in financial firms. I am sure they use different algorithm. But this is my instinct though.

Comment: (necroposting, sorry) - TomCat it's entirely possible to have a useful calculator that represents irrational numbers symbolically, and we often see this in CAS calculators. The key here is that we keep thinking symbolically until the very last step, where we approximate and output a number.

Answer (score 3):

They do as long as you don't use one that uses symbolical calculations like the modern TI or Casio calculators.

One way to see it is to calculate iteratively roots of a number and then square the results again, if you do it often enough you will get a different result than the input due to numerical errors, this doesn't only have to do with the floating point representation but also with inaccurate root algorithms used in the calculator.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly floating point error comes from the fact that certain numbers can't be represented in certain bases without using repeating numbers. For example, 10/3  can't be represented in base 10 without using repeating trailing 3's and so there's technically a precision error if you don't indicate the numbers keep repeating. However, 10/3 in base 3 is represented as 10.1. Binary has the same problem, and so some answers that are easy to represent in base 10, are repeating in base 2, and so when doing the conversion back and forth you get a precision error, but it's because the computer was doing best approximation, just like writing 10/3 = 3.33333333333, is technically wrong.
.1 + .2 = 0.30000000000000004 is actually a pretty good approximation. The actual technicalities of floating point error are a little more complicated but for example, .1 can't be represented in binary without repeating numbers.

Comment: "Repeating" is not the issue: you have round-off error with irrational numbers as well.